# Search strings with "indexOf" fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to display the message `Exist!` if the strings in the `input` field includes strings within the `li` tags.

When I input `cccc`, the `Exist!` message appears successfully. However when I input `aaaa` or `bbbb` it fails and displays `Nop!`. I'm wondering why. I hope someone help me.

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  var keyword = $(this).val();
  var targetText;
  var msg = $('#msg');
  
  if (keyword != '') {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
      targetText = $(this).text();
      if (targetText.indexOf(keyword) != -1) {
        msg.text('Exist!');
      } else {
        msg.text('Nop!');
      }
    });
  } else {
    msg.text('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div id="msg"></div>
<ul>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbbbb</li>
  <li>cccccccccc</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Because it is overwritten each time

Comment: You should probably only change your text to Exist or Nop once after your loop

Comment: A key skill for any programmer is to be able to debug their code. Get familiar with your browser's developer tools, especially the debugger, and step through the code as it is running so you can see what is happening in each iteration.

Comment: put "return false;" after Exist msg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because you update the text in every loop. If you follow the logic through after you press `a`, the first iteration will find the `li` containing `aaaaaa` and update the text to `Exist!`. The second iteration will then compare `a` to `bbbbbb` and fail and set the text to `Nop!`. The same for the last iteration on `cccccc`

To fix this you could instead use `:contains()` to find any element which has the text entered and show the message:

```js
var $msg = $('#msg');

$('input').on('input', function() {
  var keyword = $(this).val();
  var matches = $('ul li:contains("' + keyword + '")');
  $msg.text(matches.length ? 'Exist!' : 'Nop!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div id="msg"></div>
<ul>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbbbb</li>
  <li>cccccccccc</li>
</ul>
```

Note that `:contains()` makes greedy matches, ie. entering `aa` will match `aa` but also `aardvark`. If you want an exact match, use `filter()` instead:

```js
var $msg = $('#msg');

$('input').on('input', function() {
  var keyword = $(this).val();
  var matches = $('ul li').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() === keyword; // convert cases to have a case-insensitive match
  });
  $msg.text(matches.length ? 'Exist!' : 'Nop!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div id="msg"></div>
<ul>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbbbb</li>
  <li>cccccccccc</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice one on the contains selector, I guess he wants his greedy match, since he is using indexOf

Comment: True, I thought I'd add both just in case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations. Now I understand why only last one of the lists was working. I'm also grateful that you showed me another option.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping over all the elements and checking each one. So for `aaa` you have a match so you write out the text. Then you go to the next one and there is no match, so you set the text to not found.

So you need to exit the loop when a match is found. With jQuery's each, you can use return false.

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  var keyword = $(this).val();
  var targetText;
  var msg = $('#msg');
  
  if (keyword != '') {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
      targetText = $(this).text();
      if (targetText.indexOf(keyword) != -1) {
        msg.text('Exist!');
        return false
      } else {
        msg.text('Nop!');
      }
    });
  } else {
    msg.text('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div id="msg"></div>
<ul>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbbbb</li>
  <li>cccccccccc</li>
</ul>
```

Other way you can do it is with filter

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  var keyword = $(this).val();
  var msg = $('#msg');
  var lis = $('ul li');
  
  if (keyword != '') {
    var lisWithText = lis.filter( function () {
      return this.textContent.indexOf(keyword) != -1
    });
    $("#msg").text(lisWithText.length ? "yes" : "no");
  } else {
    msg.text('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div id="msg"></div>
<ul>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbbbb</li>
  <li>cccccccccc</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now I understood what was happening..As you told me only by adding "return false", my code worked.
Your code with "Filter" also worked nicely!

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the text while inside loop (`.each`), because it is overwritten on every iteration, that's why just the last sentence `ccccc` works, because it is the last loop iteration, the others get overwritten.

You can use a flag variable to know if exists or not, then after loop, check this boolean variable and set the text based on it.

Take a look in this example:

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {

  var keyword = $(this).val();
  var targetText;
  var msg = $('#msg');
  var exists = false;
  
  if (keyword != '') {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
      targetText = $(this).text();
      if (targetText.indexOf(keyword) != -1) {
        exists = true;
      }
    });
    
    if (exists) {
      msg.text('Exist!');
    } else {
      msg.text('Nop!');
    }
    
  } else {
    msg.text('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div id="msg"></div>
<ul>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbbbb</li>
  <li>cccccccccc</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but each will run through all, even when you return (in fact, in this context, `return` doesn't make a difference)

Comment: ah, yes, it's correct, altough the final result works

Comment: Any controversy???  I tried your code with "flag" and it worked fine!

Comment: yes, it works, it is just not the best performatic solution as the one you've accepted above. If you think it helped, you can upvote

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Array.prototype.some` method to return as soon as the callback returns true, and then set your message based on having an answer or not, for example like the following:

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  var keyword = $(this).val();
  var msg = $('#msg');
  if (keyword != '') {
    var hasKeyword = Array.from( $('ul li') ).some(function( item ) {
      return item.textContent.includes( keyword );
    });
    msg.text(hasKeyword ? 'Exists' : 'Nop!');
  } else {
    msg.text('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div id="msg"></div>
<ul>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbbbb</li>
  <li>cccccccccc</li>
</ul>
```

Also, to simplify, you can use `string.prototype.includes` for verifying if the string contains a substring

Comment: Your code worked fine! I didn't know this Array.From(). Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**This code snip wii work for case insensitive also**

```js
$('input').on('input', function() {
  var keyword = $(this).val();
  var targetText;
  var msg = $('#msg');
  
  if (keyword != '') {
  var matchfound=false
    $('ul li').each(function() {
      targetText = $(this).text();
      debugger;
      if (keyword.trim() && targetText.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(keyword.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1) {
        msg.text('Exist!');
        matchfound=true;
      } 
    });
    if(!matchfound){
            msg.text('Nop!');
         }
  } else {
    msg.text('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div id="msg"></div>
<ul>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>bbbbbbbb</li>
  <li>cccccccccc</li>
</ul>
```